# Block interaction on UIWebView while keeping its scroll functional

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, scroll

Is it possible to disable all the interactions on a `UIWebView` but its scrolling?  I know links could get blocked by implementing the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol, but Javascript interactions that don't load any webpages don't trigger the `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block interaction with the site, but allow scrolling, one approach would be to put a `UIScrollView` over the `UIWebView`. Then:

- Update your scroll view's content size to match the web view's content size
- In your scroll view's `scrollViewDidScroll:` method, update the web view's `scrollView.contentOffset` to match your scroll view's

This will allow panning through (and you can use a similar approach to enable zooming if you like). It won't allow tapping, or text selection though.

Comment: Sounds good, let me give it a try before accepting your answer.